# Google Places Request Returning "REQUEST_DENIED"

Tags: xamarin.ios, google-places-api

I realise their are numerous questions regarding this issue and I have read them all, but I still cannot get this to work!

I have:

- Created my project in the API console
- Enabled Places API in services
- Created a new IOS API Key (repeated this step twice now)
- Tried the request with sensor=true, sensor=false and no sensor param at all
- Tried HTTP and HTTPS

Those are all the fixes I found within the existing questions regarding this issue, have I missed anything? Here is a sample URL I am using to test:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?sensor=true&query=Test%20sd&key=MYKEY

And yes, I am replacing 'MYKEY' with my actual API key :).

I am developing an IOS app using monotouch but I don't really see how that is relevant as I can't get this to work in the browser either.

Any help would be hugely appreciated! Been stuck on this all day now.

Comment: Further note: I am successfully using the Google maps IOS SDK with the SAME api key that I am using to submit the places requests so the API key must be valid for places right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to be using your "Simple API Access" key (not an Android/iOS key).  The documentation mentions this as the last step.

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#Authentication

I tried your sample URL with my Simple API Access key and it was successful.

Comment: I'm an idiot.. Thanks so much for that pointer, I had actually tried it with my browser key at some stage but was probably using an invalid url or something.